# why zip(*k) can't work when k is a iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

```
c = [1,2,3,4]
k = iter(c)
a = zip(*k)
```

The console shows that:
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
But k is obviously iterable.

Answer (score 3):

argument #1 in your case is the integer `1`- which does not support iteration.

this on the other hand will work:

```
c = [range(3), range(3)]
k = iter(c)
a = zip(*k)
```

now argument #1 is a `range` object which supports iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Note that by unpacking, you are essentially doing the same as:

```
zip(1,2,3,4)
```

Which also raises:

> TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration

Given that the first element it encounters is not an iterable, and as specified in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), `zip` is used to:

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements *from each of the iterables*

So if you want to use `zip`, make sure you're feeding it iterables.

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening, lets try to print `*k`

```
In [1]: c = [1,2,3,4] 
   ...: k = iter(c) 
   ...: print(*k)                                                                                                              
1 2 3 4
```

What did we see here, we got 4 integers in our case, but that is not an expected. (Also equivalent to `zip(1,2,3,4)` as per [yatu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56040626/8591431)

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

> zip(*iterables) .
>   Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.

So we need to pass it an iterator, which we are not doing as we see here

Hence we will pass an iterator to zip as the docs say

```
In [10]: c = [1,2,3,4]                                                                                                         
In [12]: list(zip(c))                                                                                                          
Out[12]: [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
```

Also zip is useful when we have atleast 2 iterators, with one iterator it doesn't work, but if we have a list of lists, then the unpacking would work

```
In [13]: c = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]                                                                                             

In [14]: a = zip(*c)                                                                                                           

In [15]: list(a)                                                                                                               
Out[15]: [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Because unpacking `c` gave the `zip` two iterators, which were the sublists inside the bigger list!

Answer (score 0):

LLTTP (little late to the party).

One part of these problems is to make it work with the minimal effort and provide meaningful results. Here is what I would do:

```
# Python 3.x
c = [1,2,3,4]
k = iter(c)
a = zip(k,k)
list(a) #    [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```